# How to solve problem with activating WooCommerce if it shows a fatal error?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem with WooCommerce installing. It shows that The plugin was not activated because it caused a fatal error.

> Warning:
> require(/...../...../domeenid/www....../htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Autoloader.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /....../...../domeenid/www....../htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
> on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/...../...../domeenid/www....../htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Autoloader.php'
> (include_path='.:') in
> /...../...../domeenid/www....../htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
> on line 24

**It causes by this codes**:
// Load core packages and the autoloader.
`require __DIR__ . '/src/Autoloader.php';`
`require __DIR__ . '/src/Packages.php';`

Can somebody explain what does it mean?

Comment: what is your php version? What version of wordpress are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post, but I ran into the same issue and came here from a search. Downloading a fresh woocommerce plugin solved it for me.

The issue may have been caused by an error updating the plugin with wp cli and php 7.3, FWIW.